# Filter a long JSON file for jQuery Autocomplete Plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I need a little tip from you folks today in regards to the jQuery Autocomplete - exactly saying - the Bootstrap's Typeahead Plugin (isn't really different in functionality from the jQuery Autocomplete).

The source to the Autocomplete is a local JSON variable with is present in another javascript file which contains the below information

```
var autoResults = [
{"name":"SOME-NAME","type":"SOME-TYPE","manuf":"SOME-MANUF"},
{"name":"SOME-NAME","type":"SOME-TYPE","manuf":"SOME-MANUF"},
{"name":"SOME-NAME","type":"SOME-TYPE","manuf":"SOME-MANUF"},
{"name":"SOME-NAME","type":"SOME-TYPE","manuf":"SOME-MANUF"}
]
```

Now the issue is that these items exceed over 10,000 in number at the moment and the file has become 1.35Mb. It would increase even further because the items are supposed to be 100,000 in production.

Is there any possibility that I could either divide the file into parts but keep the same variable - concatenate the JSON variables into one JSON variable before load etc.

But in either case the files would be loaded = 1.35Mb in total from the server - so confused. I am using a local variable just to save the server searching for autocomplete queries with over 100,000 records at a time.

Any other tips in handling the same would be appreciated. In the mean time I shall try the http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ which seems awesome but doesn't really solve the file size problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest that this data be placed in a database. That way the filtering can be completed server side by the database. Do you have the ability to get this data into a database?

Comment: I'm not a database guru but my guess is you are over-thinking the server resource savings vs taxing the client download. 100,000 entires isn't large for a DB and with decent connection speeds AJAX autocomplete works fast

Comment: @JoeFletch Yes, I have the data in the DB - I have created the JSON Javascript file from that data only. Charlietfl - Can I test the performance on these in some way? I am using CodeIgniter as the PHP Framework. Do you really think searching 100,000 records would not create that much load when say 200 users are doing it simultaneously? Please suggest!

Comment: Plus I am totally not in favor of client downloading the JS file - I too want it to come from the DB - probably seeking the quickest way possible. Thanks!

Comment: Leave the data in the database and use the autocomplete functionality from an external data source. [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: 100,000 records get searched in microseconds at DB end. Setting up a live test demo to try it yourself doesn't take long

Comment: Thanks folks - I will stick to your suggestions.